ubuntu 24.04 gnome-shell is uesing 80% of cpu on all cores
I recently replaced windows 11 with Ubuntu 24.04. I noticed that 50% of the CPU are constantly in use on all cores. When i move my mouse it can get up to 90%, which makes the system quite laggy.
It is a fresh install and have no extensions installed. I did upgrade the NVIDIA driver to the newest version (550-somthing). what can i change so that gnome-shell is using less CPU?
here are my system details:
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-08-05 21:22:15

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Microsoft Corporation Surface Studio 2
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-7820HQ × 8
Graphics:                                    Software Rendering
Disk Capacity:                               1.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            536.902.768
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-39-generic

Htop

Did you use the linux-surface and note questions about that add-on should go to GitHub.
